# How to implement an ad hoc network?

Tags: c#, adhoc

I want to write an application based on ad-hoc network by using WiFi on windows(or android), but I don't know how to begin. I have some questions as follow:

Do I need to implement routing protocol?

Do I need to implement a client or server or both on one device?

How to Connect multiple devices to each other?

I can use C# or JAVA, Can anyone recommend some information?

Please forgive me for my poor English, Thanks.

Comment: This question is too broad -  _there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy, 
just to answer a few of those questions:

- Routing: yes, you need a special routing protocol for an ad hoc network, since according to 802.11 there is nothing specified for multihop routing in ad hoc nets per default. For windows the only one i know avaible and built is OLSR-Routing. Check for OLSR Daemon. For linux there are much more built. But the choice which routing protocol you are using are strong dependent on the network structure and mobility behaviour of the nodes. Google for routing protocols in MANET (Mobile Ad Hoc Networks) or MeshNetworks.
- C#: there is a  NativeWifi API for .NET which enables you to do a lot of things in Wireless networks (including Ad Hoc) like connection and so on....
- Client/Server: in an ad hoc network a node acts not as a client or server, it acts as a router so to say...

Hope i could help
Rene

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, the word you said "in an ad hoc network a node acts not as a client or server, it acts as a router" wake me up! Thanks! : )

Comment: Just because i faced this problem right now: once you use an ad-hoc routing app or made your own once, you have to allow windows to do IP Forwarding. Do this by setting the registry key to 1 at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ System\ CurrentControlSet\ Services\ Tcpip\ Parameters" and set "IPEnableRouter" to 1! Otherwise the windows node (which should act as a router) would not forward packets.